# Using AlternateKey with condition using Code-first approach

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, constraints

I'm trying to implement an AlternateKey constraint on a table. However I was wondering if it was possible to implement a constraint based on a specific condition.

For example, I have table of records:

| ID (Primary Key) | Organization ID | Year | IsDeleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19b0b3a0-61d8-40b4-9af2-1a48ce18fa56 | 14 | 2022 | False |
| 9c355c7d-f0fd-4187-8886-8c367ca3852b | 15 | 2022 | False |
| db4b8d3c-6cff-4c38-ae03-0baac6277e94 | 16 | 2022 | False |
| d1147e62-20c1-4129-aa63-2553b1e205e5 | 17 | 2022 | False |
| 6c6175bf-6d95-4606-84a3-4f90bb1aa644 | 18 | 2022 | False |

As per my constraint, the alternate key should be a pair of the columns Organization ID and Year. However that should only be enforced if the property "IsDeleted" is False. Meaning I want to be able to have more than one row with the same Organization ID and Year pair with IsDeleted as True.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

| ID (Primary Key) | Organization ID | Year | IsDeleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19b0b3a0-61d8-40b4-9af2-1a48ce18fa56 | 14 | 2022 | False |
| 9c355c7d-f0fd-4187-8886-8c367ca3852b | 15 | 2022 | False |
| db4b8d3c-6cff-4c38-ae03-0baac6277e94 | 16 | 2022 | False |
| d1147e62-20c1-4129-aa63-2553b1e205e5 | 17 | 2022 | False |
| 6c6175bf-6d95-4606-84a3-4f90bb1aa644 | 18 | 2022 | True |
| 607e2465-7a77-4fd4-9b95-29d445ac76c3 | 18 | 2022 | True |
| ffe645c3-456f-46f7-b580-2aa7abc3e313 | 18 | 2022 | False |

In EntityFramework I can easily create the constraint like this:

`modelBuilder.Entity<Record>().HasAlternateKey(x => new { x.OrganizationId, x.Year });`

What would be the next step to implement this logic?

Comment: Which database source are you using? Can you use a standard Unique constraint rather than Alternate Key constraint?

Comment: I'm using MSSQL. I will check whether the Unique constraint can solve my problem

Comment: I think _alternate key_ is entityframework-speak for _uniue constraint_. (Drives me nuts when people think of a new name for something that already has a name.)

Comment: As for now I just figured out how to enforce this constraint by using the following SQL Script:

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX only_one_row_with_deleted_set_to_false
    ON Records (OrganizationId, Year) WHERE (IsDeleted = 0);

This ensures that only one OrganizationId + Year pair can exist if the condition "IsDeleted" is set to false (0 in sql).

Answer (score 0):

After you've created a unique index (`AlternateForeignKey(...)` is short for `HasIndex(...).IsUnique`) you can then go ahead and create a foreign key that references it something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OtherThing>(entity =>
                entity.HasOne(ot => ot.Thing)
                    .WithMany(t => t.OtherThing)
                    .HasForeignKey(ot => new {ot.OrganisationId, ot.Year})
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .HasConstraintName("OtherThing_FK_Thing");
```

assuming that you've set up a navigation properties `OtherThing.Thing` and `Thing.OtherThings`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that the solution to my problem is not to use the ALTERNATE KEY, but instead the UNIQUE INDEX constraint.

The code-first approach is at this point not necessary for me. If I try to create a new entry in the table in C# that conflicts with the constraint, I will handle it in the code eg. by writing `catch (DbUpdateException e)`.

So by executing the following script in SQL I create a conditional constraint for the entities that has IsDeleted set to false, thereby ensuring that only one key pair of OrganizationId and Year can exist that is not deleted:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Unique_OrganisationId_Year_Active
    ON Records (OrganizationId, Year) 
    WHERE (IsDeleted = 0);
```

EDIT: changed the name of the exception from "SqlException" to "DbUpdateException", since this was the correct exception being thrown when inserting/updating an entry that would result in a constraint conflict.